# How to get user input of a grid of characters in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, grid, user-input

I'm pretty new to Python, so I am not aware of its syntax very much.

So I want to give in an as input the number of rows and columns of a grid, and then input a grid of characters constrained by the number of rows and columns. For example:

If my input is:

```
3 4
X O X O
X X X X 
O O O O
```

I want to print out an array like this:

```
grid = [['X', 'O', 'X', 'O'], 
        ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X'], 
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
```

What I have so far is:

```
row, column = [int(x) in x for raw_input().split()]
grid = []

for i in range (0, N):
    grid[i].append([])
    grid[i] = raw_input().split()
```

I am getting the error: List index out of range.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Input is coming from STDIN?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `grid` is an empty list. You can't reference `grid[i]` where `i` is out of range.

You need to `append` to `grid`, like this:

```
for i in range(N): # 0 is implicit
    grid.append(raw_input().split())
```

No need to append to `grid[i]`

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem is `grid` is an empty array, but you are trying to append to element `0`, which is not possible.

You can solve this problem, with list comprehension, like this

```
rows, columns = map(int, raw_input().split())
grid = [raw_input().split() for i in xrange(rows)]
```

It is the same as writing

```
grid = []
for i in xrange(rows):
    grid.append(raw_input().split())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grid = []
for i in range (0, N):
    grid.append([])
    grid[i]=raw_input().split()
print grid
```